# Third public prime

Tags: rsa

Suppose $m$ is a huge publicly known prime, like one of GIMPS Mersenne primes. Let $p$ and $q$ be large primes. If I let $n = pqm$ and do RSA
$$c = x^{e} \mod n$$
$$x = c^{e'} \mod n$$

Where $ee' = 1 \mod \phi(n)$, is there any weakness introduced that would not have been present had I done RSA with $n = pq$? How about if $m$ was an arbitrary publically known huge prime (not Mersenne).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the introduction of an extra public prime factor $m$ in the public modulus $n$ would cause a serious security issue: the adversary knowing $e$, $m$, and ciphertext $c=(x^e\bmod n)$, but not $x$, can find $x\bmod m$, which is a leak about plaintext (representative) $x$, that has no equivalent in RSA with all prime factors of $n$ secret.

That is because
$$\begin{align}
c=(x^e\bmod n)&\implies c\equiv x^e\pmod n\\
&\implies c\equiv x^e\pmod m\;\text{ [since $m$ divides $n$]}\\
&\implies c^{(e^{-1}\bmod(m-1))}\equiv x^{e(e^{-1}\bmod(m-1))}\pmod m\\
&\implies c^{(e^{-1}\bmod(m-1))}\equiv x\pmod m\\
&\implies (x\bmod m)\;=\;(c^{(e^{-1}\bmod(m-1))}\bmod m)\\
\end{align}$$
Note: Obtaining the but-last line makes uses of a corollary of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem): for any prime $m$, for any integer $x$, for any integer $k\ge0$, it holds that $x^{k(m-1)+1}\equiv x\pmod m$.
For $w>0$, the notation $u\equiv v\pmod w$ means that $w$ divides $u-v$; and the different notation $u=(v\bmod w)$ additionally means that $0\le u<w$.

Leaking $x\bmod m$ makes it such that the increase in ciphertext size caused by the introduction of $m$ comes with no increase in the useful plaintext capacity compared to textbook RSA.

In all the above, it is immaterial whether prime $m$ is a Mersenne prime or not.

Leaking $x\bmod m$ could be a practical issue, or not, depending on context; further, $m$ being one less than a power of two (by definition of a Mersene prime) could make things more damaging than for a haphazard prime $m$, by making the relation between $x$ and $x\bmod m$ simpler at the bit level.

---

There is another possible issue: it must be that $e$, times the bit size of $x$, remains very large compared to the bit size of $n$, which got increased by the introduction of $m$ (possibly a lot, since we know large Mersenne primes). Otherwise, the system could fall to the $e^\text{th}$ root attack, which simplest form relies on having $x^e<n$, allowing to compute $x$ from $c$ by taking its non-modular $e^\text{th}$ root.